# При клонировании репозитория изменяется кодировка

Tags: git

Клонировал репозиторий и после git status показывается следующая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P. S. При копировании по ftp нет никаких преобразований в крякозябры

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. 2. приложите ёще к вопросу **текстовый** вывод программы *locale* на обоих компьютерах.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, во втором случае это UTF-8 + CP1251.

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/i18n.txt *Note that Git at the core level treats path names simply as sequences of non-NUL bytes, there are no path name encoding conversions (except on Mac and Windows).*

Comment: Про двойные кодировки https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/147843/

Comment: Какая у вас ОСь? Версия git?

Comment: Версия git: msysgit 2.14.1.1 ОС: windows